# Best way to sort a nested array (returned value vs sort & math.max)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, return-value

I've been wondering... Is it possible to access a returned value from a function/code block that is nested inside another code block?

For example, I am trying to sort values in an array from largest to smallest using the .sort() method, and then take the largest from each nested array and push it to a new array:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    arr[i].sort(function(a,b) {
      return b - a; // trying to access this new, organized array
    });
    var newArr = [];
    newArr.push(arr[i][0]);
  }
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: `.sort` sorts the array in place, so `arr[i][0]` will work fine. Are you asking whether there is a shorter way to do this? FWIW, `newArr` is completely useless here.

Comment: Right now the sort method sorts the arrays just fine. The problem is accessing those sorted arrays. When I try and access them outside of the .sort() function, I get the original (unsorted) arrays.

Comment: I doubt that. `arr[i][0]` will give you the largest value. Again, the issue is rather that you are not doing anything with `newArray`.

Comment: arr[i][0] is currently resulting in: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: No it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/tsgLj0sv/ . Your code executes fine. But again, you are not doing anything with `newArr`, and you are creating a new array in each iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need to sort the array. You could use `Math.max`.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(function (el) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, el);
  });
} // [ 5, 27, 39, 1001 ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8rdso94a/)

Comment: nice... you win (as long as it's a number... as long as it's a number). :-)

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    arr[i].sort(function(a,b) {
      return b - a; // trying to access this new, organized array
    });
    results.push(arr[i][0]);
  }
  return results;
}

var results = largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: That works, yep! Thanks a lot! I marked Andy's answer as the correct answer, however - only because it makes use of a shorter method!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to access a returned value from a function/code block that is nested inside another code block?

You can only get the return value if you call the function. You are not calling the `.sort` callback, it is called inside `.sort`, so you cannot get its return value.

---

I assume you are asking because the code you have doesn't work as you expect. Looking at your code, it appears obvious that, while you sort the array, you are not really doing anything with it after you sorted it. As I already said in my comments, the way you use `.sort` and access the largest value is perfectly fine.

I think you want to declare `newArr` outside the loop and return it from the function:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].sort(function(a, b) {
      return b - a;
    });
    newArr.push(arr[i][0]);
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]));
```

There is also a more streamlined way of writing this, that doesn't mutate the input array:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(innerArray) {
    return innerArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a > b ? a : b;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that results in the same thing. I'm still only getting the original, unsorted arrays. ```return newArr``` doesn't output anything, either.

Comment: I had a typo, but other than that it works perfectly fine. Try it again.

Comment: Thanks! I marked Andy's answer as the correct one, though. Only because it seems to be a more efficient method (without using sort).

Comment: @Jose: In that case I suggest to update your question and reformulate it to ask what you really want to know. Because, while the accepted answer fixes your code, it doesn't seem to answer your question.

Comment: TBF I should write a bit more in my answer :) But it was really meant as an "As an aside..."

Answer (score 0):

> trying to sort values in an array from largest to smallest using the
>   .sort() method, and then take the largest from each nested array and
>   push it to a new array:

Try using `while` loop , `.push()` `.sort()` , `.reverse()` . `largestOfFour` returns two arrays , whose indexx can be toggled at `return` statement ; largest number from each array at first array , arrays in array sorted from largest to least at second array

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var res = [], i = arr.length - 1;
  while(i > -1) {
    res.push(Math.max.apply(Math, arr[i].sort(function(a, b) {
      return Number(b) - Number(a)})
      )); 
  --i;
  };     
  return [res, arr.reverse()]
}
```

```js
var input = [
    [4, 5, 1, 3],
    [13, 27, 18, 26],
    [32, 35, 37, 39],
    [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
  ];

function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var res = [], i = arr.length - 1;
  while(i > -1) {
    res.push(Math.max.apply(Math, arr[i].sort(function(a, b) {
      return Number(b) - Number(a)})
      )); 
  --i;
  };     
  return [res, arr.reverse()]
}

document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0]
.textContent = JSON.stringify(largestOfFour(input), null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Why sort if you use `Math.max` anyway?

Comment: You don't need to sort the array as well as use `Math.max`.

Comment: @FelixKling _"Why sort if you use Math.max anyway? "_ As interpreted here from OP _"am trying to sort values in an array from largest to smallest using the .sort() method, and then take the largest from each nested array and push it to a new array:"_, two separate return results were expected; 1) sorted arrays, 2) max of each sorted array

Comment: Ah I see. But in that case I would use `return val[0];` instead of `Math.max`. (I assumed the OP only sorted in order to get the largest value).

Comment: @FelixKling _"But in that case I would use return val[0]; instead of Math.max."_ Yes, that would be briefer . Have to ingrain to use array notation where possible . If single array was expected , could use `[0]` within first `.map()` at `.sort()` to avoid any further calls